# reshaping R dataframe from an existing one

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df

```
Feature Sample Value
A S1 12
A S2 15
B S1 13
B S2 11
```

I want to convert it to the format

```
   S1 S2
A  12 15
B  13 11
```

I don't know how to do this in R

Comment: If the second column is called `V2` you can do `data.table::dcast(as.data.table(df), ... ~ V2)`

Comment: `xtabs(Value ~ Feature + Sample, df1)`.